# ngSwitch set preselected value in ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I have the following code.

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="place">
  <ion-segment-button value="prehospital">
    Prehospital
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="hospital">
    Hospital
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="dx">
    Dx - Symptoms
  </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="place">

  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'prehospital'"></ion-list>
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'hospital'"></ion-list>
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'dx'"></ion-list>
```

Now, when the page opens, it is blank and the user must tap on one of the three choices above in order to see the content. How can I set a preselected value and when user taps to open the page, one of the three choices (ex hospital) will open by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to initialize your `place` variable with something on your .ts file.

Let's say you have `place: string;`, you can use `place: string = 'hospital'` instead.